# how do I display this Airline array from the header file?

Tags: c++, project

Okay so I am working on a project for my C++ class and i'm trying to code this project in baby steps but i swear i can not figure out how to display this thing! here is my code so far

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

#include "C:\Users\barta\OneDrive\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Project 4\Project 4\array.h"

void displayPlane(char[ROW][COL]);
//void getData(int &, char &);

int main()
{
    displayPlane(layout);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
void displayPlane(char[ROW][COL])
{
    for (int r = 0; r < ROW; r++)
    {
        cout << r + 1 << " ";
        for (int c = 0; c < COL; c++)
        {
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the header file

```
//arrays for airline problem

const int ROW = 9;
const int COL = 4;
const int CTR = 3;

//initial seats in the plane
    char layout[ROW][COL] = {  { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' },
                            { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' },
                            { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' },
                            { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' },
                            { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' },
                            { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' },
                            { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' },
                            { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' },
                            { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' }};

    int classCtr[CTR] = {0,0,0};

    string classes[] = {"First Class", "Business Class", "Coach"};

    double fare [] = {500, 300, 100};
```

Every time i run the code it displays this kind of error

"one or more multiply defined symbols found" & 
"   _main already defined in array2Dimen.obj"

Now trust me I know its something stupid but I can't seem to figure it out please help!

Answer (score 0):

What you first need to learn is the difference between *declarations* and *definitions* What you have in the header file (and the source files) are *definitions*. In a header file you should only have *declarations*.

For example:

```
extern char layout[ROW][COL];
```

is a *declaration*, but

```
char layout[ROW][COL] = { ... }
```

is a *definition*. The same goes with functions

```
int main();
```

is a *declaration* (also known as a function prototype) but

```
int main() { ... }
```

is a *definition*.

The errors you are getting say that you are somehow defining some things multiple times, for example by including your header file in multiple source files, causing all the variables defined in the header file to be defined in all [*translation units*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_%28programming%29) (roughly a source file with all included header files).

You also seem to be defining the `main` function in multiple source files.

Comment: Thank you i actually fixed the issue, turn out i forgot i added another cpp file to my project and I guess it was trying to run both '